# как настроить локальный сервер XAMPP на отправку почты?

Tags: php, email, smtp, xampp

Учусь php и на первом серьёзном задании затык, гуглил все советы относятся к периоду до 2012года у меня в настройках другие параметры

в php.ini

```
[mail function]
```

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP=localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port=25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = me@example.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
;sendmail_path =

; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters
; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
; the 5th parameter to mail().
;mail.force_extra_parameters =

; Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will include uid of the script followed by the filename
mail.add_x_header=On

; The path to a log file that will log all mail() calls. Log entries include
; the full path of the script, line number, To address and headers.
;mail.log =
; Log mail to syslog (Event Log on Windows).
;mail.log = syslog

в sendmail.ini

```
[sendmail]
```

; you must change mail.mydomain.com to your smtp server,
; or to IIS's "pickup" directory.  (generally C:\Inetpub\mailroot\Pickup)
; emails delivered via IIS's pickup directory cause sendmail to
; run quicker, but you won't get error messages back to the calling
; application.

smtp_server=mail.mydomain.com

; smtp port (normally 25)

smtp_port=25

; SMTPS (SSL) support
;   auto = use SSL for port 465, otherwise try to use TLS
;   ssl  = alway use SSL
;   tls  = always use TLS
;   none = never try to use SSL

smtp_ssl=auto

; the default domain for this server will be read from the registry
; this will be appended to email addresses when one isn't provided
; if you want to override the value in the registry, uncomment and modify

;default_domain=mydomain.com

; log smtp errors to error.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable logging

error_logfile=error.log

; create debug log as debug.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable debugging

;debug_logfile=debug.log

; if your smtp server requires authentication, modify the following two lines

auth_username=
auth_password=

; if your smtp server uses pop3 before smtp authentication, modify the 
; following three lines.  do not enable unless it is required.

pop3_server=
pop3_username=
pop3_password=

; force the sender to always be the following email address
; this will only affect the "MAIL FROM" command, it won't modify 
; the "From: " header of the message content

force_sender=

; force the sender to always be the following email address
; this will only affect the "RCTP TO" command, it won't modify 
; the "To: " header of the message content

force_recipient=

; sendmail will use your hostname and your default_domain in the ehlo/helo
; smtp greeting.  you can manually set the ehlo/helo name if required

hostname=

Comment: Долго мучился со стандартным `sendmail`, в итоге настроил почту с помощью `msmtp`. Вот: [хорошая статья](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-gmail-or-yahoo-with-php-mail-function).

Comment: Спасибо, буду изучать, жалко что на английском(

Comment: Никогда не поздно учиться, тем более что в нашем деле без английского никуда. Могу посоветовать [расширение Google Translate](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-translate/aapbdbdomjkkjkaonfhkkikfgjllcleb?hl=ru) — помогает: если при чтении встречаете незнакомое слово/словосочетание, то выделяете его, затем кликаете по появившейся иконке расширения, после этого получаете перевод. Ну и основы английского прочтите где-нибудь — дальше дело за практикой :).

Comment: да да именно им и пользуюсь при прочтении статьи которую вы посоветовали0

Comment: Ещё, на всякий случай (я [искал ответ](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-gmail-or-yahoo-with-php-mail-function?comment=44657) по этому поводу некоторое время), владелец `/etc/.msmtp_php` должен быть `daemon`.

Comment: ок, спасибо огромное)